# How to pass the Google Analytics client id by using hidden field in gravity form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using **ga function** to get the Google Analytics client id of each user who visit my website but its working perfectly on Google analytics UI. When I pass the client id of cookie "_ga" in hidden field its shows different client id because due to of cache enabled in my website. Is there any solution to solve.

**Google Analytics:**

```
ga(function(tracker){var c1Id = tracker.get('clientId');});
```

Also I'm using Add filter method in gravity form to pass the clientId. But it's no luck.